# Problema al abrir txt alojado en servidor

Tags: php, html, descarga

El caso es que tengo una web en la que tengo un enlace donde al pulsarlo se descarga un txt que tiene varias líneas, por ejemplo es así:

> 123455
>
> 456789
>
> 234566
>
> 234354

Pero al descargarlo y abrir el archivo en mi pc, aparece el archivo así:

> 123455456789234566234354

Sin saltos de línea, y no tengo ni idea de porque puede estar pasando esto ya que en el servidor está el archivo correctamente subido (con sus saltos de línea). Lo he probado en todos los navegadores y en todos ellos se descarga el archivo sin saltos de línea.

Este es el código php que se encarga de descargar el archivo:

```
$fichero = $_GET['nombre'];
$basefichero = basename($_GET['nombre']);

header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

header( 'Content-Length: '.filesize($fichero));

header( 'Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=' .$basefichero);
readfile($fichero);`
```

¿Que podría estar pasando ahí?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Que editor de texto estas usando para abrir el archivo? Yo te recomendaría que uses cualquier menos `Notepad`.

Comment: Utilizo el bloc de notas.

Comment: `Notepad` en español es `Bloc de notas`, no lo uses. Si usas otro editor vas a poder ver los saltos de linea.

Comment: Efectivamente, con cualquier otro se ven los saltos de línea OK. Entonces, ¿cómo se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo estás viendo en windows, que usa [saltos de linea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nueva_l%C3%ADnea#Representaciones) del tipo "`\r\n`" también llamados `CR` (carriage return - retorno de carro) y `LF` ( line feed - avance de línea).

Windows toma esta forma por compatibilidad con [MS-DOS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) que lo hereda de [CP/M-80](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), y era una forma de estandarizar salida por pantalla y salida por impresora, que en esa época eran mas onda máquina de escribir eléctrica o [teletipos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletipo).

Para quienes se preguntan: qué es un "carro", y por qué debe "retornar"? ver el vídeo de un teletipo funcionando en modo manual https://youtu.be/ObgXrIYKQjc?t=1m20s

Unix/linux han implementado el "fin de línea" con un sólo caracter `LF` y dejan que el dispositivo (si tiene carro, se encargue de retornar el carro a la posición inicial de la línea).

En el caso de [Microsoft Notepad - Bloc de Notas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloc_de_notas) recién soporta mostrar bien los saltos de línea (`CR`, `CR`+`LF`, `LF`) desde [mayo 2018 en la versión insider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/)

### En resumen el archivo tiene saltos de línea unix `LF` y tu versión del bloc de notas no los muestra porque le falta el `CR`.

Para reemplazar los saltos de línea al enviar el archivo hay varias maneras, incluyo 2:

**1) con [file($fichero)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file.php) leemos el archivo a un array de líneas, ignoramos los saltos de línea originales y reconstruimos el archivo con `"\r\n"`.**

```
<?php

$fichero = $_GET['nombre'];
$basefichero = basename($_GET['nombre']);

// por seguridad tendrías que limitar a una sola carpeta
// para evitar por ej: getfile.php?nombre=/etc/passwd
$carpetaTextos = __DIR__ . '/textos/';
$fichero = $carpetaTextos . $basefichero;

if (file_exists($fichero)) {
  header( 'Content-Type: text/plain');
  header( 'Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=' .$basefichero);

  // lee el archivo a un array de lineas
  $contenido = file($fichero, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  $contenido = implode("\r\n", $contenido);

  echo $contenido;
}
exit();
?>
```

---

**2) con [file_get_contents($fichero)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) leemos el archivo y reemplazamos `"\n"` por `"\r\n"`.**

```
<?php

$fichero = $_GET['nombre'];
$basefichero = basename($_GET['nombre']);

// por seguridad tendrías que limitar a una sola carpeta
// para evitar por ej: getfile.php?nombre=/etc/passwd
$carpetaTextos = __DIR__ . '/textos/';
$fichero = $carpetaTextos . $basefichero;

if (file_exists($fichero)) {
  header( 'Content-Type: text/plain');
  header( 'Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=' .$basefichero);

  // leer el archivo y reemplazar
  $contenido = file_get_contents($fichero);
  $contenido = str_replace("\n","\r\n",$contenido);

  echo $contenido;
}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: no se podria usar la herramienta unix2dos?

Comment: si, pero es mas que nada una "falla" del bloc de notas que en breve estará arreglado y disponible para todos los usuarios de windows. o incluir en la generación del archivo el `\r` todo depende del uso final que se le dé al archivo, si es para verlo nomas hay alternativas gratis para el bloc de notas

Comment: Pero yo no quiero decir a los usuarios que se lo descarguen que no utilicen el bloc de notas, solo quiero que al descargarselo, sea cual sea el editor con el que lo abran, se vea bien. ¿Esto sería posible? Efectivamente, si lo abro con cualquier otro se ve bien. Pero me gustaría solventar este problema ya que la mayoria de los usuarios utilizan el bloc de notas

Comment: Tamaño promedio de los archivos? quién o qué los genera? que tipo de servidor es?

Comment: Tamaño promedio de cada archivo? 1 - 2 kb. Los he generado yo escribiendo en ellos y los he subido a una carpeta del servidor, al darle al enlace se descarga ese archivo. Tipo de servidor? Es uno linux. Más sobre él no sé.